# Edit the DotNetNuke skin CSS of the website using the admin panel

Tags: asp.net, css, module, dotnetnuke, admin

I have created a dotnetnuke skin and packaged it and installed it on client server but the client want himself to change the colors of the skin from admin panel. Is there any option that client himself can change the colors from admin. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNN doesn't expose the ability to edit any of the SKIN.CSS files, but you could put the CSS into Portal.css and override any of the Skin level classes there.

Portal.css can be edited from the Admin/Site Settings page in DNN